# Count of total groups required. Group by cluased query in MySql

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I want the count of a total groups.

I have following query. I want how many groups this query returned based on web_id. Lets suppose if it grouped under 4 groups. I need count 4.

```
select * from web_details where redirected = false group by web_id
```

I hope my question is understood.

Comment: May you fix the spelling of _cluased_ in your title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out how can I do this.

The ideas was so simple but I was not clicking it.

```
select count(*) from 
(
    select * from web_details 
    where redirected = false group by web_id
) as temp;
```